# adding column in sql/oracle query with CASE yields 'invalid character'

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to use CASE to make a new column in my query based on a current column: FISCAL_DAY. Hoping this can work, below is what I have tried. Keeps erroring 'invalid character'.

```
SELECT qm_plan, prod, base_prod_plan, entry_point
     , fiscal_day, updatetime, TSW_A_VALUE, TSW,
       CASE
            WHEN fiscal_day > ($Now - DURATION(28*90*90)) THEN 'M1'
            WHEN fiscal_day > ($Now - DURATION(60*90*90)) AND fiscal_day < ($Now - DURATION(28*90*90)) THEN 'M2'
            WHEN fiscal_day > ($Now - DURATION(90*90*90)) AND fiscal_day < ($Now - DURATION(60*90*90))  THEN 'M3'
            WHEN fiscal_day > ($Now - DURATION(120*90*90)) AND fiscal_day < ($Now - DURATION(90*90*90)) THEN 'M4'
       END AS FISCAL_RANGE
FROM ama_owner.qm_stocker_actual_usage_hist 
  UNPIVOT(
  TSW_A_VALUE
  FOR TSW
  IN (tsw_01, tsw_02, tsw_03, tsw_04, tsw_05, tsw_06, tsw_07, tsw_08, tsw_09, tsw_10, tsw_11, tsw_12)
  )
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
ORA-00911: invalid character
*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual.
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 32
```

Comment: `$Now` and `DURATION` are not available in oracle. '$now` can be replaced with `SYSDATE` or `SYSTIMESTAMP`. i didn't undersatnd what you want to do with duration ?

Comment: The error message seems pretty self-explanatory. `$Now` is an invalid identifier for the reason given: *identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than letters and numbers.* Actually, that may be a documentation bug because identifiers can't start with numbers either. But either way, `$` isn't a valid character to start a name with.

Answer (score 1):

You've been told *everything*. `$Now` is an invalid identifier, as far as Oracle is concerned.

What does it (the `$` sign) represent? If it is a bind variable, try `:`. If it is a substitution variable, try `&`. If none of above, what is it, then?

Did you, by any chance, want to say "right now"? If so, try to use the `sysdate` function instead, e.g.

```
when fiscal_day > sysdate - duration (28*90*90) then
```

(presuming that `duration` is a function you created).